# How to play FLV video in IE browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, flv

I cant play a flv video in IE browser,I using the following code to play a flv video in simple html page, it will works in firefox and chrome, but it not play in IE browser all version,

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="250" height="200" title="myMovieName" id="myMovieName">

<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/IhyPCKOLNko?version=3">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="loop" value="false">

<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/IhyPCKOLNko?version=3" width="250" height="200" loop="false" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>

</object>
```

What i did wrong in this code?
Can any one give me suggestion to play a flv video in IE browser?

Regards,
Karthik.

Answer (score 2):

best to embed in swf:

```
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http:/ download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/
     cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="400" height="300" 
     id="flashvideoplayer.swf" align="middle">
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
      <param name="movie" 
               value="http://www.myhomepage.com/flashvideoplayer.swf?
               flv=http://www.myhomepage.com/myvideofile.flv">
      <param name="quality" value="high">
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
     <embed src="http://www.myhomepage.com/flashvideoplayer.swf?
               flv=http://www.myhomepage.com/myvideofile.flv" quality="high"         bgcolor="#ffffff" width="400" height="300" name="flashvideoplayer.swf" 
     align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
     </object>
```

Comment: I am getting blank rectangle box in IE browser.This code is not working in IE.

Comment: What version of IE do you have? Also check your IE/Windows Security Settings. Objects may be disallowed.